# How can I add resource handlers dynamically in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources

I have this piece of code:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/images/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:static/dragontail-9.11.1/9.11.1/img/")
            .resourceChain(true);
}
```

I would like to support updating the data files during runtime whenever there is an update I can download.  Therefore, I need to be able to support changing that version number at run time.  I could use a variable for this, but the problem is that *I need to support multiple versions at once*.

I have a `HashSet` that manages the currently supported version numbers.  How can I go from that to dynamically matching the resource handlers to it?

I have also tried using ant matchers in the `.addResourceLocations` which would help, but it seems as if ant matchers are only supported in `.addResourceHandler`

---

I believe I've resolved the issue - dealing with path matching directly should allow me to change resource paths at runtime.  We can extend `AntPathMatcher#match` to match resources to URIs arbitrarily.  I have not actually tried this yet but it doesn't seem like there should be a problem doing so.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/images/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:static/dragontail-9.11.1/img/")
            .resourceChain(true);
}

@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
    configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this as Resource Handler. Can't you just access the file location?

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?  I'm open to one :)  I have thought of creating a controller to handle this dynamically but I'm only serving static content and it seems as if this is the standard way to do it.

Comment: Yes for a static way this is the standard way but if you need it dynamic you could create a simple servlet or do you maybe have a reverse proxy in front of your app? The you could use that

Comment: I think I might have figured it out...  I will update the OP.